# how to solve the problem: " expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>" when saving

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Every file saving I get the error:

```
 raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
```

and then can't access anymore to that the saved file (when I'm opening it manually)

```
open and load succesfully the file with openpyxl library:
book = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\shoshana\PycharmProjects\pandas\doh_golmi.xlsx')
```

Saving with:

```
book.save(r'C:\Users\shoshana\PycharmProjects\pandas\doh_golmi_2.xlsx')
```

Then

```
import openpyxl
......
openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\shoshana\PycharmProjects\pandas\doh_golmi.xlsx')
....
book.save(r'C:\Users\shoshana\PycharmProjects\pandas\doh_golmi_2.xlsx')
```

expected of course to be able to save changes I do in the file and get access after that to the file when I'm opening it manually.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, and I was using the cell.fill incorrectly. In other words, I was doing something of the sort

```
import openpyxl
openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\some\file.xlsx')
...
yellow = openpyxl.styles.colors.Color(rgb='FFFF00')
cell.fill = yellow 
...
book.save(r'C:\some\file.xlsx')
```

The above is incorrect, you have to use a PatternFill (see below)

```
import openpyxl
openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\some\file.xlsx')
...
yellow = openpyxl.styles.colors.Color(rgb='FFFF00')
filling = openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=color)
cell.fill = filling
...
book.save(r'C:\some\file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I couldn't load the file.
The only way was to manually open it, save it and load it.

My workaround for it is to convert the file using libreoffice:

I ran this command line in my jupyter notebook:

```
!libreoffice --convert-to xls 'my_file.xlsx'
```

this creates a new xls(no x) file named my_file.xls, this file can be opened now with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment so I'll do it like this:

JDArango's answer works but watch out that xls has stricter row and column limits. When there are too many rows/columns the conversion will just throw them out without giving any warning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34329681)